# How can I run an app in fullscreen?

Tags: python-2.7, libavg

I want to run an app in fullscreen. Here is what I found so far:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib_app = app.App()
    res = player.getScreenResolution()
    lib_app.run(MainDiv(), app_resolution=''+str(res.x)+'x'+str(res.y))
```

The size is correct, but the window is not fullscreen. Additionally the fullscreen-button is disabled. There is another function I played with: [setResolution](https://www.libavg.de/reference/svn/player.html#libavg.avg.Player.setResolution)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib_app = app.App()
    res = player.getScreenResolution()
    # setResolution(fullscreen, width, height, bpp) bpp=16 or 24 is valid
    player.setResolution(True, int(res.x), int(res.y), 16) 
    lib_app.run(MainDiv())
```

But when I run this version the code is ignored.

How can I make it to start in fullscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some researching I found a solution and i want to share it with you: app.run() can have several settings and it has an fullscreen option

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib_app = app.App()
    res = player.getScreenResolution()
    lib_app.run(MainDiv(), app_fullscreen='True', app_resolution=''+str(res.x)+'x'+str(res.y))
```

The full list of settings is not documented and cannot be found in settings.Settings as the documentation of [run](https://www.libavg.de/reference/svn/app.html?highlight=settings#libavg.app.App.run) suggests, but it can be found in the code of [app](https://github.com/libavg/libavg/blob/master/src/python/app/app.py#L190) at github.

```
self._settings.addOption(Option('app_windowconfig', ''))
self._settings.addOption(Option('app_resolution', '640x480'))
self._settings.addOption(Option('app_window_size', ''))
self._settings.addOption(Option('app_fullscreen', 'false'))
self._settings.addOption(Option('app_show_cursor', 'true'))
self._settings.addOption(Option('app_rotation', 'normal'))
self._settings.addOption(Option('app_panel_fontsize', '10'))
self._settings.addOption(Option('app_mouse_enabled', 'true'))
self._settings.addOption(Option('multitouch_enabled', 'false'))
self._settings.addOption(Option('multitouch_driver', ''))
self._settings.addOption(Option('multitouch_tuio_port', ''))
self._settings.addOption(Option('log_avg_categories', ''))
```

Please notice that the values are strings.

Comment: The possible settings are displayed if you run the app with '--help' as a parameter.